# Hide ToolBar on Fragment Scroll

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

so my ToolBar is in my MainActivity layout, along with a container underneath it for the fragments. All fragments have a ScrollView, I would like to hide the ToolBar when a Fragments scrollview is scrolled. What is the best way around having the fragment and main activity communicate?

Answer (score 1):

To communicate between `activity` and `Fragment`, implementing an interface is the best option i know. Read more about it here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html